# More fields in page layout for lookup fields

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-object, lookup-field

I would like to see more than one field or some other field from the custom object in look-up fields on the page layout and on the dialog, which opens when the user hover-over the field. How it's possible for custom objects?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using **Compact Layouts**:

1. Go to Object Manager → Open the Custom Object
2. Go to Compact Layout → Click on System Default
3. Clone it and create a new Compact Layout. Select the fields to be shown on the Layout. Save the Layout. (*Note : You can also edit and use the System Default Layout*)
4. Click on Compact Layout Assignment. Select the Primary Compact Layout and Save.

For details, please check [Compact Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.compact_layout_overview.htm&type=5) and [Compact Layout Limitations and Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.compact_layout_notes.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi @Sneh, Thanks for your help. It really worked on the dialog but can I show more information in the field?

Comment: @itsaboutcode - Please update your question with details on what additional information do you need to show.

Comment: The Lookup field only shows the field label and the `Name` of the related object. The compact layout provides the other, configured detail. If you want otherwise you will have to create your own component and switch to using custom and/or dynamic forms. If you have to do things differently (personally I would push hard against this), you can solve this for (at least your custom) objects that have a text-based Name field by adding a trigger that generates the value for the `Name` field, based on the fields you want to show, when the record is created or one of the relevant fields is updated.